# How to prevent indent, unindent (>>, <<) from re-aligning text?

Tags: indentation, whitespace

Is it possible to make indenting/unindenting not re-align text, eg:

```
/*
 * Some Text
 */
```

Indents to:

```
    /*
    * Some Text
    */
```

I would prefer/expect:

```
    /*
     * Some Text
     */
```

---

*I saw spacemacs has an option for this, was curious to know if vim does too.*

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by having

```
set shiftround
```

Set in the `.vimrc`

Comment: I find `shiftround` a very useful setting >95% of the time. For the remaining cases, I typically use block insert (select start lines with `<C-v>`, then use `I<Tab><Esc>`) to work around it.